# Add UserType to Login Form Access 2013 password and username and usertype

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I just wasted more than 7 Hours trying to solve this problem that I had When I was trying to make a Login Form,

I have tblUsers that has :

```
UserID |   UserName | Password  | UserType

1      |    Admin   | password  | admin

2      |   Mark     | password2 |  BSS
```

I wrote this code :

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Dim bCanSafleyClose As Boolean


Private Sub btnLogin_Click()
Dim rst As Recordset

Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * From tblUsers WHERE UserName = '" & txtUserName & "' AND Password = '" & txtPassword & "' AND UserType ='" & cmbxUserType & "';")

If rst.RecordCount = 1 Then
bCanSafleyClose = True
DoCmd.Close
If cmbxUserType = "Admin" Then  ==> This failed I don't know why
DoCmd.OpenForm "AdminMain"
End If
If cmbxUserType = "NSS" Then
DoCmd.OpenForm "ReportsMain"
End If

Else
MsgBox "Error!"
bCanSafleyClose = False

End If

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
bCanSafleyClose = False
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
'Cancel = Not bCanSafleyClose
End Sub
```

But that is doesn't working !

I hope that someone Can figure out this problem and help me to solve it :)
Thanks ..

Comment: The user shouldn't need to enter their "user type", only their username and password.  You already have the type defined in the user table. Validate username/pw against your users table, returning the UserId and UserType.  It would help to explain exactly what it is you want to achieve here.

Comment: What Im trying to do that I have an App , and I have more than one Manager but they have different privileges, which means I want when the Admin put user name : admin and his password so when He click on Login its will redirect to AdminMain , in the same Form, if the Manager put his username and his password and click on Login button will redirect him to ManagerMain and so on ..

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
Private Sub btnLogin_Click()

    Const USR_TYPE_ADMIN As String = "Admin"
    Const USR_TYPE_NSS As String = "NSS"

    Dim rst As Recordset, ut As String

    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT UserType From tblUsers WHERE UserName = '" & _
                                 txtUserName & "' AND Password = '" & txtPassword & "'")

    If Not rst.EOF Then

        bCanSafleyClose = True
        ut = rst.Fields("UserType").Value

        If ut = USR_TYPE_ADMIN Then
            DoCmd.Close '<<added
            DoCmd.OpenForm "AdminMain"
        ElseIf ut = USR_TYPE_NSS Then
            DoCmd.Close '<<added
            DoCmd.OpenForm "ReportsMain"
        Else
            'anything else?
        End If


    Else
        MsgBox "Error!"
        bCanSafleyClose = False
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Nothing Happend, the code is ok but no results no fails,
Here is the link of the LoginDemo : 
https://files.fm/down.php?i=xnsyjjy7&n=LoginDemo.zip

I think there is no way to have more  than 2 usertypes, I searched on google, seems no one try that before!? wired ..

Comment: See my edit above - try that. Your link is not accessible: try dropbox instead.

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit




Private Sub btnLogin_Click()
Dim UserLevel As Integer

If IsNull(Me.txtUserName) Then
MsgBox "Please Enter username", vbInformation, "LoginID required"
Me.txtUserName.SetFocus

ElseIf IsNull(Me.txtPassword) Then
MsgBox "Please Enter Password", vbInformation, "Password required!"
Me.txtPassword.SetFocus

Else
'process the job
If (IsNull(DLookup("[UserName]", "tblUsers", "[UserName] ='" & Me.txtUserName.Value & "'  And Password = '" & Me.txtPassword.Value & "'"))) Then
MsgBox "Incorrect User or Password"

Else

    UserLevel = DLookup("SecuirtyLevel", "tblUsers", "[UserName] ='" & Me.txtUserName.Value & "'")
    DoCmd.Close
        If UserLevel = 1 Then
    'MsgBox "LoginID and Password is correct"
    DoCmd.OpenForm "AdminMain"

    ElseIf UserLevel = 2 Then
                  DoCmd.OpenForm "ReportsMain"
                  ElseIf UserLevel = 3 Then
                  DoCmd.OpenForm "ReportsMain"
                                Else
                            DoCmd.Close
                            End If
                            End If

        End If

End Sub
```

Thank you Andre and Tim :)